# How can i log runtime exception using TinyLog

Tags: logging, tinylog

While doing experiment over tinylog the issue i am facing is am not able to print the run time exception logs.

For ex. int a =0 ;int b = 10;int c = b/a;

As this will give arithmetic exception but this is not getting recorder in logs.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to catch the runtime exception and pass it to the logger:

```java
import org.tinylog.Logger;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int a = 0, b = 10;
            System.out.println(b / a);
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            Logger.error(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Alternatively, you can also use an [UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) for logging uncaught exceptions:

```java
import java.lang.Thread.UncaughtHandler;
import org.tinylog.Logger;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new TinylogHandler());
        int a = 0, b = 0;
        System.out.println(a / b);
    }

    private static class TinylogHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            Logger.error(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it be possible without try catch. As i want to see if any of my code fails and i have not written that inside try catch.

Comment: Instead you could use an [UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://medium.com/@yosimizrachi/c72e013da092) for logging uncaught exceptions.